# Any recommendation for a good enough Winforms GUI design?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, design-patterns

I am developing a mid-size application with VB2008. To better test my application I am following a MVP/Supervising Controller approach.

My question is: What are your recommendations to separate responsibilites? So far I've come up with a winform with an instance of a controller and with an instance of my class. The controls are updated via DataBinding

The problem is that I'm just not sure where to write the responsibilites (let's say Validation, Report creation, Queries and so on)  Inside my class? in a separate class?

Is there any small example of a clean Winform class design that you could point me?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you spend time reading Jeremy Millers '[Build your own CAB](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx)' series of posts to get a feel for what you might like/need to implement as your application becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler is a good source of information on all things design patterns including MVC. Fowler discusses Passive View and separation of responsibilities is demonstrated also

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html